How can I configure SSH on my laptop to use a Control Master on a remote gateway?
I have a server, let's call it server, which requires a 2FA authentication every time. So, I can set up ssh multiplexing to reduce the number of required authentication.
However, I usually carry my laptop around, so the internet connection on my laptop isn't stable. I'm currently using another server, let's call it gateway, to connect to the server, so I persist the connection on gateway and I can use ssh gateway ssh -tt server.
However, in my current setup, I can't use VSCode's remote ssh plugin to connect to the server through the gateway. I've tried setting ssh -tt server as the RemoteCommand which doesn't work.
Is it possible to use ssh to forward the control master socket from gateway to local then use the forwarded socket on my local side to connect to the server? How can I configure it?

have you tried ssh -J gateway server?

Yes, however it don't work. I think proxyjumping handles the authentication on the local side, but I want the authentication to be handled on the gateway.

I've tried forwarding the control master socket on the gateway to local using ssh -L and it don't work either -- local ssh client complains 'connection closed' on the socket
